# Guice scenario where multiple injector references appear unavoidable

Tags: java, guice

I have a use case where it appears that referencing a Guice injector from multiple locations is the only solution—though this is generally discouraged.

My application is built on top of Talend, an open source ETL platform. Most of my actual application is in Java classes that are called by Talend components. These components include Java snippets that I write and that, in turn, instantiate/invoke my classes.

Now I intend to use Guice throughout my Java classes but there is absolutely no way for me to inject dependencies into the Talend components (so that they would be available to the Java snippets). Instead, I need to actually create these dependencies. I’d like to at least have Guice control the instantiation, which means that instead of using `new`, it appears that the only way I can instantiate my classes (the ones with `@Inject` constructors) is to call `injector.getInstance`. This, in turn, implies that I need to keep the injector around, presumably using an old-fashioned factory that creates it in the first place and makes it available as a singleton.

I just can’t see any other way to handle this but perhaps I’m missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider [static injection](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Injections#Static_Injections). This will still hide persistent references to your injector across your app, but it will save you from having to pepper your code with `injector.getInstance(...)` calls. In any case you can inject `Injector` if you really need to.

```
class TalendDependencyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {
    requestStaticInjection(ExtractorDependencies.class);
    requestStaticInjection(ProcessorDependencies.class);
  }
}

public class ExtractorDependencies {
  @Inject private static Provider<ParserService> parserServiceProvider;
  @Inject private static Provider<SomethingElse> somethingElseProvider;

  private ExtractorDependencies() { }

  static ParserService getParserService() {
    return parserServiceProvider.get();
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Once again, Jeff, your reply is spot on. I am extremely grateful; your assistance is making a palpable difference in my ability to plan the Guice migration, which must happen quickly.

I confess that after reading about static injection a week or so back, I mentally discarded it as something I wouldn’t sully my code with. That’ll teach me to refrain from geek snobbery :-)

Comment: I do want to confirm one thing. Consider the statically injected provider, `parserServiceProvider`, that you invented above. `ExtractorDependencies.getParserService()` will be called downstream in the policy conversion process. Indeed, `ParserService` may have injected dependencies, such as PolicyContext (see  <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847558/guice-puzzler-batch-scoped-encapsulated-context>), that are _batch scoped_ and won’t actually be available until what I’ll call the `PolicyScope` is seeded. I just want to confirm that those injected dependencies will honor that scope.

Comment: Whenever you call "get" on that Provider, that's when the object will actually be instantiated (assuming the object being provided isn't actually a singleton). When you inject an instance of something rather than a Provider, Guice will implicitly call the Provider for you, so the logic still holds. You can think of a Scope as a centrally-configured Provider decorator, and the Provider that your scope returns (as in SimpleScope) happens to be an anonymous inner class--which should protect you from accidentally saving the wrong PolicyContext where it doesn't belong.

Comment: Valid approach but I would personally not use static injection. I'd prefer to set these providers manually as part of the application's bootstrap process. This creates more visibility on what is really happening.

Comment: @RobbieV Fair enough, though part of the point of Guice is to reduce the (very visible) boilerplate--after all, setting them manually is very visible, but is also more of a maintenance burden. Just a matter of style, and of balancing complexity.

Comment: @JeffBowman as per the doc
`requestStaticInjection() is a crutch. Guice includes this API to ease migration from a statically-configured application to a dependency-injected one. New applications developed with Guice should not use this API.requestStaticInjection() is a crutch. Guice includes this API to ease migration from a statically-configured application to a dependency-injected one. New applications developed with Guice should not use this API.`

Comment: @WitVault This is pragmatic, yes, driven by the requirement that Talend (as I understand it) creates Java classes and is also Guice-naïve. Your quoted docs are intended to steer people toward _constructor injection_ and other _testable solutions that minimize the use of Injector scattered throughout the code_, which is also what my answer does; it's the best I could find given that Talend and Guice both want to create the objects here. Someone more familiar with Talend may have a clever alternative; if you aren't using Talend, please ask a separate question that conveys your constraints.

Comment: @JeffBowman I have posted a new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61853490/how-to-avoid-google-guice-injector-getinstance-repetative-calls-due-to-null

Please let me know If I am doing something very incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many Talend objects you have but you might want to consider using providers. For instance suppose you have your own class that you want Guice to manage creation of:

```
public interface INotTalendControlled {}
public class NotTalendControlled implements INotTalendControlled {}
```

This will be added to a Talend object whose dependencies cannot be injected via Guice (although I assume there is some manual process for doing so either constructor or setter):

```
public class TalendControlled {
        private INotTalendControlled notTalendControlled;

        private TalendControlled(INotTalendControlled notTalendControlled) {
            this.notTalendControlled = notTalendControlled;
        }

        public INotTalendControlled getValue() {
            return notTalendControlled;
        }
    }
```

If you want Guice to manage these lifecycles and the lifecycle of Talend controlled objects you can use a provider like so:

```
public static class TestModule extends AbstractModule {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(INotTalendControlled.class).to(NotTalendControlled.class);
            }

            @Provides
            public TalendControlled provideInjectsToTalendObject(INotTalendControlled notTalendControlled) {
                return new TalendControlled(notTalendControlled);
            }
        }
```

The  @Provides method will hide of the use of new for all objects as you can now directly inject TalendControlled objects (@Inject TalenControlled talendControlled) and an explicit injector is not needed to construct their dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Ryan. Unfortunately, I have no ability to employ `@Inject` annotations in the Talend controlled code. I don’t even have reliable access to the name of the underlying Talend component class into which my Java code is inserted. In all cases, the Talend Java code I write is simply treated as a code fragment that is executed by Talend in accordance with my job design. Because this is so limiting, most of my Talend Java code (i.e. Java code in Talend components) is extremely concise, simply calling into the actual Java classes that have the bulk of my application logic.