# How to avoid Google guice injector getInstance() repetative calls due to null?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, vert.x

I have recently started using Google guice DI framework and am quite new to it.
I am facing below problem - 
@inject returns null always and have to call injector to inject various references.

This is my **AbstractModule** class

```
public class AppModule extends AbstractModule {

    private static final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppModule());

    private final Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(new VertxOptions().setMetricsOptions(
            new DropwizardMetricsOptions().setEnabled(true)
    ));

    private final com.test.reactivex.db.service.DBService dbService;

    public AppModule() {

        this.dbService = DBService.createProxy(this.vertx, DB_SERVICE_ADDRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Vertx.class).toInstance(this.vertx);
        bind(EventBus.class).toInstance(this.vertx.eventBus());
        bind(FileSystem.class).toInstance(this.vertx.fileSystem());
        bind(SharedData.class).toInstance(this.vertx.sharedData());
        bind(com.test.reactivex.db.service.DBService.class).toInstance(this.dbService);
        bind(AppConfig.class).toProvider(AppConfigProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
        //requestStaticInjection(AppDependenciesInjector.class);
        logger.info("Google guice module configuration done");
    }

    @Provides
    public static AppConfig appConfig() {
        return injector.getInstance(AppConfig.class);
    }

    public static Injector getInjector() {
        return injector;
    }
}
```

This is how I am using injector to inject dependencies, but problem is that I have to use injectors again.

```
public class GraphQLRouter {

    @Inject 
    private static AppConfig config;

    @Inject
    private com.test.reactivex.auth.service.DBService dbService;

    public GraphQLRouter() {
    // below code I want to avoid
        if (dbService == null) {
            dbService = AppModule.getInjector().getInstance(com.test.reactivex.auth.service.DBService.class);
        }
    }

    //below code I want to avoid
    static {
        if (config == null)
            config = AppModule.getInjector().getInstance(AppConfig.class);
    }
```

Comment: @JeffBowman please help

Comment: Curious if you've sorted this out?  How and where do you create/inject the `GraphQLRouter`?

Comment: @kendavidson still not sorted. GraphqlRouter I use to combine with main root router.

Comment: You have to initialize a `GraphqlRouter` instance somewhere.   You're not binding to it in your `AppModule` so I'm not sure where or how you're using it.   If you're calling `new GraphQLRouter()` that's never going to be injected automatically.

Comment: Another question, is where are you using your `vertx` to create the server and apply the routes?  In a main `class Application` or something along those lines?

Comment: in Main class application

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a terrible answer off the bat, but I'll modify it as more information comes in.  The important piece here is that:

1) Your `GraphQLRouter` class is using field based injection due to the `@Inject` being on the field, one of those fields is static, which means you're breaking it up even more.

2) You're then attempting to use the `dbService` in your constructor, that's just never going to work - it's always going to be null.

It all depends on where you're using it.  I don't know (pretty much anything) about VertX, so if you need more with regards to that I'll have to do some googling, but you should not mix up all the different types of injections (field, constructor, static).

At a minimum you can use:

```
@Inject
public GraphQLRouter(AppConfig config, DBService dbService) {
    this.config = config;
    this.dbService = dbService;
}
```

At this point you're in  a better point for the purpose of testing, but we're still missing where you're creating the instance from.

**Edit**

I did a little reading on Vert.x and had some ideas, they all involve pulling the line

```
private static final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppModule());
```

out of the `AppConfig` and into your `public static void main(String[] args) {}` method.   Are you using Verticals? Or are you using Vert.x without verticals?  Apparently you can do it, but there is no real information on how you would do it (so I'll assume the former).  Again, this is just an idea, but you need to move the injector up:

```java
public class RandomVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  @Inject
  private GraphQLRouter router;

  @Override
  public void start() {
     // use router
  }
}

public class Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       private static final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppModule());

       Vertx vertx = injector.getInstance(Vertx.class);
       vertx.deployVerticle(injector.getInstance(RandomVerticle.class));
   }
}
```

This would require that you provide some kind of binding to the Verticles, which you should probably do anyhow.  The documentation talks about being able to use a `VerticleFactory` which you could implement yourself so that:

```
vertx.deployVerticle("guice:com.example.SomeVerticle");
```

was run through something like a:

```
public class GuiceVerticleFactory implements VerticleFactory {
   public GuiceverticleFactory(Injector injector) {
       this.injector = injector;
   }
}
```

so you can inject the verticles during creation, but again, I didn't look into the Factory very much, so who knows.

Hopefully it helps.